# background image not repeating on column

Tags: css, background-image

Having an issue with the background image on the right hand column. Am expecting it to repeat vertically as and when the main content area changes in height.

Any help would be appreciated

here is my CSS

```
 #rightcol {
        background: #86030b url(images/leftcol-bg.jpg) top repeat-y;
        height:100% !important;
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
        width: 210px;
        padding: 20px auto;
      }

Here is some more of my CSS

    #content-wrapper {
width: 930px;
height: 100%;
margin: 10px auto;
}

#content_main {
height: 100%;
padding: 14px;
top: 0px;
background: #fff;
width: 692px;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#rightcol {
background: #86030b url(images/leftcol-bg.jpg) top repeat-y;
height:100% !important;
text-align: center;
float: right;
width: 210px;
padding: 0px auto;
  }
```

thanks for all your help so far

Comment: I just made a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XNcx/) and it seemed to work fine, repeating the background vertically.

Answer (score 0):

All parent elements, including the body tag, need to have height 100% set to have your "rightcol" fill the entire height of the page.

Here is a little light reading that might help http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#rightcol {
    background-image:url('images/leftcol-bg.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    height:100% !important;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 210px;
    padding: 20px auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put both your main content and right column in a `div` that wraps both, and put the background on that div.